# React router integration with react-uwp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uwp

I am writing to write an application with react, react-router and react-uwp. react-uwp(https://www.react-uwp.com) is an implementation of Window UI guidelines.
If I am including react-router 'Link' component, it is not working(throwing errors.). When I replace react-router 'Link' with react-uwp 'Link' component then hyperlink functionality working as expected.

Comment: which errors are thrown when you use `Link` from react-router? please add more details